# Is it possible to live both in Sweden and the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, sweden

I would like to know if it is possible to live both in Sweden and the Uk at the same time. I am a European citizen, and have permanent resident in the UK. I also have the Swedish Personal Number (although I am not Swedish national).

Since I work as a free-lancer, I work across different countries in Europe and would like to be based in Sweden and the UK (where I live and have paid taxes for almost 10 years). I think that one may live in both countries at the same time, pay taxes in both countries, as long as I commute between them, but can only pay social contributions in one of them.

I know that in the UK this is possible, but I am unsure about Sweden, as I don't speak Swedish.

- What are the consequences of this in Sweden?
- Do I need to have foreign health insurance or how does it work?
- Do I keep the social rights?

Comment: What is your specific nationality? This is a key detail.

Comment: UK has tax year from April to April, and That will be used for things as residency as well. Other countries are usually based on calendar years. It may be possible to be more than half a UK year in the UK, and more than half the calendar year in Sweden, for several years in a row, and with careful planning. No holiday in a Spain for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions:** Since portions of your question **are not clear**

- you are an EU-Citizen (not all European Citizens are EU Citizens)
- UK is your **main** residence, where you have lived for 10 years, paying taxes with National Health and Pension contributions

---

**UK:**

If you have not done so already, apply for the **[EU Settlement Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families)**

Once this process has been completed, you **will be known** to the UK authorities, which at the moment you are (most probably) **not**, since the UK has no general residency registration system.

With such a status you may leave the UK for up to 2, 4 or 5 years depending on the time recognized and citizenship without effecting your residence status.

https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/what-settled-and-presettled-status-means

This will be a **Brexit**-safe solution.

---

**Sweden:**

As an EU Citizen you have the right to work and live in Sweden.

If you desire to maintain a **secondary** residence in Sweden, inform them of your **primary** residence in the UK and that you will be commuting between both.

---

**Healthcare:**

Since you are insured by the National Health system, you (should) be covered by the European Health Insurance while in Sweden.
(Look at the back of your National Health Card and compare with the images shown in the link below)

https://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=559

**Note:** this may change based on the **final outcome of Brexit**!

---

**Taxes:**

As always, a world of its own, which must be dealt with properly.

Comment: Good luck with the tax man he will love you for all the extra taxes you will pay as soon as sweden is involved :)

Comment: I would also highly recommend finding a tax advisor who knows UK & Swedish tax law, as one doesn't want to get an unexpected tax bill!

Comment: And no brexit as well good luck here